# Resources for pagoda priority queue?

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, priority-queue

I recently heard about a type of priority queue called a "pagoda" that allegedly has excellent runtime guarantees.  In fact, some of the references I've found on it have suggested that it's one of the fastest priority queue implementations available.  Surprisingly, though, I can't seem to find a single good resource on this data structure anywhere on Google or Bing.

Does anyone know of any good resources (analysis, source code, etc.) on this data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pagodas: pg 174 of the "Handbook of Algorithms and Data Structures" by G.H. Gonnet (published 1984). Contains psuedocode and analysis.

There is a more recent version of this book [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201416077).

Comment: Do you know if this is available online somewhere?  Or will I have to purchase a copy for this one section?

Comment: @templatetypedef: you haven't upvoted, and yet you want me to do the work to find you a free online version?

Comment: My apologies - I didn't intend it that way.  Because you gave a specific page number in the book, I was curious if you had found an online version of it.

Comment: @templatetypedef: I've owned the book since 1987.